# How to apply different rules on inline elements of a node in XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to transform a xml with the help of xslt while the xslt is getting generated with the help of java by reading a rule file.

Suppose the Xml is something like this.

```
<root>
    <p> This is <span>India</span> &amp; is <span>tolerant</span> enough to <span>live</span>normal black here</p>
    <p> Well <span>Pakistan</span> ,<span>Srilanka</span>, <span>Bangladesh</span>,<span>China</span> is our neighbouring country</p>
</root>
```

I want the 1st span of first p to be coloured in green & the second is not mapped so be in normal black & the third to be blue.

Similarly there can be more no. of inline elements can occur & will have different rules.

Similarly the second "p" will have different rules for different inline elements. How can i differentiate and apply this rule in xslt?

Java reads the rule file and prepares the xslt dynamically?

Can anyone please suggest how to do this?

Comment: You match your `<span>`s by position: `span[1]` ... see [XPath examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is have a series of templates, with your various rules in the conditional match. For example

```
<xsl:template match="p/span[1]">
  <span style="color:red">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/span[2]">
  <span style="color:blue">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/span[position() > 2]">
  <span style="color:green">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, in the case of matching `span` tags, you could combine them all into one template, with an `xsl:choose` instead.

```
<xsl:template match="p/span">
    <xsl:variable name="position">
        <xsl:number />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="colour">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 1">red</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$position = 2">green</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>blue</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
      <span style="color:{$colour}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT for starters

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="p/span">
        <xsl:variable name="position">
            <xsl:number />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="colour">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$position = 1">red</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$position = 2">green</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>blue</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
          <span style="color:{$colour}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response on this.This works only thing is i need to write down a lot of templates.
Thanks again Bikash